# Почему метод getInstance подсвечивается красным?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mDateDisplay;
private ImageButton mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DataStart);
        mPickDate = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.showDatePicker);
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
        });
      final Calendar c = new Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        updateDisplay();
    }
```

Вот лог ошибки:

```
Error:(37, 38) error: cannot find symbol class getInstance
```

При этом данный метод выбивает в автозаполнении. 
P.S. Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, так как новичок в этом деле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы инициализаторе класс `new Calendar` отсюда и ошибка;

```
final Calendar c = new Calendar.getInstance();
```

удалите `new` и у вас получится. (PS когда хотите обратится `static` методу какого либо класса, его не нужно инициализировать через `new`)

```
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```